# Define: Terraform - AWS - aws_instance - user_data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, autoscaling

I'm working with Terraform, launching an ECS cluster.

I'm using a script that was written by someone else.  I understand most of the launch configuration script, other than this one point:

I'm trying to find the link between the autoscaling group and the ECS cluster.

I have an `aws_autoscaling_group` which uses an `aws_launch_configuration` (see below).
The `aws_launch_configuration` has a `user_data` parameter.  This is the only link between the autoscaling group and the cluster that I can find.

Looking at the links (bottom) to the documentation, it's not giving a very good explanation of 'what' `user_data` is.  Can someone please help me understand "how" the `user_data` links the autoscaling group with the cluster, and if at all possible give some example or link to what it's normally used for and how it's normally used.

```
...
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs_host" {
  ...

  user_data = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${var.cluster_name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
EOF
}
...
```

terraform apply outputs:

```
  ...
  + aws_launch_configuration.ecs_host
      ...
      user_data: "4e27e8feea0896af43ada0c647877da3766f5dcb"
  ...
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#user_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[official explanation by terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#user_data)

```
user_data - (Optional) The user data to provide when launching the instance. Do not pass gzip-compressed data via this argument; see user_data_base64 instead.
```

Offical aws document to explain what's `user_data`

**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html**

So in general, after you define the launch configuration and autoscaling group, the autoscaling group will make sure how many ec2 instances need be started (desired capacity).

When start a new instance, it will reference the launch configuration, which define which AWS AMI for the instance and what init command will be run. the init commands are saved in `user_data` script.

In your case, the user data script registers itself to nominated ECS cluster. So ecs cluster can discover these ec2 instances easily

```
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${var.cluster_name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

In background, there is a docker container called `amazon/amazon-ecs-agent` running to help these registions and manage other containers (ecs services)

If you want to know the details, you can go through this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html

Comment: See my updates (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) that's what you need read.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put user data is a script that is run upon bootstrapping an ec2 instance. You can automate actions that need to take place to ensure your ec2 is configured correctly, and specify them as user_data, instructing aws to run the script on machine bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

`user_data` attribute allows you to specify script payload or cloud daemon instructions. Data can be inline template as your case with the script, or file template where you will need to deal with the [Template Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html). 
So when you want to create a new launch configuration, used for autoscaling groups this is one of the option to execute here a script, and got the output as the cluster's hash for instance.

The limitations are you cannot pass gzip-compressed data via this argument; see user_data_base64 instead and you should not store sensitive data, such as passwords, as user data.